# How to center these anchor elements on the mobile version of this site?

Tags: html, css

I have a small problem with centering some anchor elements I have written. I only can't center them on a mobile version of the site, they seem to be a little bit placed to the left side. To change the style of the site for mobile version I used @media queries.

That's the code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="page">
    <ul id="icons">
        <li><object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/pl.svg"></object></li>
        <li><object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/gb.svg"></object></li>
    </ul>

    <img src="images/ryszard_final.png" alt="Ryszard Kukliński Logo" />

    <div id="buttons_div">

        <a href="biografia" class="btn1 btn1_float btn">BIOGRAFIA</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn1 btn2_float btn">RECENZJA</a>

        <div style="clear: both;" class="btn"></div>

        <a href="#" class="btn1 btn1_float btn">O PROJEKCIE</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn1 btn2_float btn">KOMIKS</a>

    </div>


    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
/******************
GENERAL
******************/

body {
    background-color: #1f1f2e;
    color: white;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

/******************
MENU PAGE
******************/
img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;

    height: 20%;
    width: 20%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.btn1 {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    text-align: center;
    height: 15%;
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    line-height: 70px;
    cursor: pointer;

    border: 3px solid #a20000;
    display: block;

    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: transparent;
    transition: 0.3s;

    margin-bottom: 15%;


}
.btn1:before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: #e60000;
    opacity: .5;
    top: -100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.btn1:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: #e60000;
    top: -100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: 0.3s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.btn1:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
.btn1:hover:before {
    top: 0;
}
.btn1:hover:after {
    top: 0;
}

.btn1_float {
    float: left;
}
.btn2_float {
    float: right;
}
#icons {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    list-style: none;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;

    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#icons li {
    display: inline-block;
}
object {
    height: 16px;
    width: 32px;

}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    #buttons_div {
        width: 75%;
        margin: 0 auto;
}
    .btn {
        float: left;
        width: 75%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    #buttons_div {
        max-width: 65%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

When I try to center it, it just doesn't work. Look at the photo below to see what I mean:
[Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g557Q.png)

As you see it doesn't work. It just pushes all buttons to the left. Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the "position:absolute;" instead of text-align in the css page,then write the position of the buttons using bot:x px ,top:y px and so on,i think that the buttons show a litlle bit to the left because of the media queries that you used

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- Place them in ul, assign li before anchor, and text-align center

or

- Place an anchor within a div, set divs width to 100% and text-align center

Answer (score 0):

In your media query @media (max-width: 480px), change the width of .btn to 100%.